# Is this code Equivalent

Tags: iphone, objective-c, syntax

I am not a fan of the following construction

```
    if (self = [super init])
{
 //do something with self assuming it has been created
}
```

Is the following equivalent?

```
self = [super init];

if (self != nil)
{
 //Do something with Self
 }
```

Comment: @codelogic why not an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes they are. The = operator returns the value.

Answer (score 2):

You may also wish to refer to Wil Shipley's take on this in his ["self = [stupid init];"](http://www.wilshipley.com/blog/2005/07/self-stupid-init.html) post.  He originally recommended

```
- (id)init;
{
 if (![super init])
   return nil;

 [...initialize my stuff...]
 return self;
}
```

but demonstrates a handful of cases where this may fail currently and may not work with some future changes by Apple.  He now recommends

```
- (id)init;
{
 if (!(self = [super init]))
   return nil;

 // other stuff
 return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Lars D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692468/is-this-code-equivalent/1692523#1692523) has your answer, but if you are looking for a way to clean up your `init` methods, I prefer the following:

```
- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init]) == nil) { return nil; }

    // your logic

    return self;
}
```

It crams all of the unpleasantness into one line, and it leaves the rest of your method free of one `if` statement (and associated parentheses).

Comment: I come from a Delphi background so I find the mixing of an assignment operator and an equals operator in an if statement overly confusing, which is why I was trying to move it out of the if statement.